# segfault at pthread_mutex_lock()

Tags: c, pthreads, locking, posix, mutex

I have a code which prints some data structure.

```
void
print_wheel_timer(wheel_timer_t *wt){

 <code to print data structure>
}

Then i sandwiched the code in-between lock and unlock mutex calls. 

void
print_wheel_timer(wheel_timer_t *wt){
pthread_mutex_lock(&wt->global_lock);
<code to print data structure>
pthread_mutex_unlock(&wt->global_lock);
}
```

And now, it segfault. 
I have disabled all threads in the code, and now program is single threaded, still a segfault.
I am using gcc, ubuntu 19.04.

gdb shows `pthread_mutex_lock()` call is screwing up data structures !!  This is weird ! 
I put the watch point on address which is being written by arbitrary value, and it shows a call to `pthread_mutex_lock()` is modifying it.  When i remove these lock/unlock calls, no segfault seen.

```
(gdb) watch *(glthread_t *)&(wt->slotlist[1].slots.right)
Hardware watchpoint 2: *(glthread_t *)&(wt->slotlist[1].slots.right)
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Printing Wheel Timer DS

Thread 1 "test.exe" hit Hardware watchpoint 2: *(glthread_t *)&(wt->slotlist[1].slots.right)

Old value = {left = 0x0, right = 0x0}
New value = {left = 0x1, right = 0x0}     <<< corruption !!
0x00007ffff7fa3934 in __GI___pthread_mutex_lock (mutex=0x5555555771d8)
at ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:80
80      ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7fa3934 in __GI___pthread_mutex_lock (mutex=0x5555555771d8)
at ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:80
#1  0x000055555555f3a2 in print_wheel_timer (wt=0x555555577180)
at WheelTimer/WheelTimer.c:276

Code :
========
void
print_wheel_timer(wheel_timer_t *wt){

int i = 0, j = 0;
glthread_t *curr;
glthread_t *slot_list_head = NULL;
wheel_timer_elem_t *wt_elem = NULL;

printf("Printing Wheel Timer DS\n");
pthread_mutex_lock(&wt->global_lock);
printf("wt->current_clock_tic  = %d\n", wt->current_clock_tic);
printf("wt->clock_tic_interval = %d\n", wt->clock_tic_interval);
printf("wt->wheel_size         = %d\n", wt->wheel_size);
printf("wt->current_cycle_no   = %d\n", wt->current_cycle_no);
printf("wt->wheel_thread       = %p\n", &wt->wheel_thread);
printf("WT uptime              = %s\n", hrs_min_sec_format(WT_UPTIME(wt)));
printf("wt->no_of_wt_elem      = %u\n", wt->no_of_wt_elem);
printf("printing slots : \n");

for(; i < wt->wheel_size; i++){
    slot_list_head = WT_SLOTLIST_HEAD(wt, i);
    ITERATE_GLTHREAD_BEGIN(slot_list_head, curr){           << segfaulting here for i = 1
        wt_elem = glthread_to_wt_elem(curr);
```

If some holy soul wants to try it out on his machine.
    pls download the code here :
    https://github.com/sachinites/tcpip_stack

```
After downloading :
switch to branch "Hellos"
git checkout Hellos
Compile :
make all
run
./test.exe
to reproduce , run the cmd : 
debug show node H1 timer
```

Now it will core in function : `print_wheel_timer()` implemented in **WheelTimer/WheelTimer.c**

Comment: you added the `global_lock` member. did you also remember to prime it with `pthread_mutex_init` or the initializer constant long-before any of this code is reached ? Also, that address look... odd. you're *sure* `wt` isn't corrupt ?

Comment: I can assure you `pthread_mutex_lock` isn't screwing up your data structures. This is most certainly UB in your code that manifests as a segfault when `pthread_mutex_lock` is called. I don't see any problems in the small amount of code provided. Please provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Valgrind can probably help as well.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, it has been initialized during program init only.

Comment: @yano updated the post with the steps to repro.

Comment: @WhozCraig `wt` is not corrupt. This is 64 bit machine, hence long addresses.

Comment: Assuming you're running on Linux, you're using an operating system that has hundreds of millions if not billions of copies running worldwide over the past decades. Just about all of those instances use `pthread_mutex_lock()` extensively.  Yet you think it's `pthread_mutex_lock()` that's corrupting your code that's been around for a few hours or days on one machine?  You need to provide a lot more evidence to make that claim.

Comment: @AndrewHenle  Sir, I am sure, something wrong with my code. I understand, Linux kernel base code cannot be erroneous.

Comment: One thing you need to do is to check the return values of your pthread function calls. As it is you have no idea if it succeeded or not. For example if you forgot to call gcc with -pthread you would be getting some errors.

Comment: I commented out the inner loop `ITERATE_GLTHREAD_BEGIN` and core is not seen. But inside this loop , only read-only operations are being performed. I am simply iterating over linked-list and printing the data.

Comment: In fact I just checked your Makefile and you use `-lpthread` which is the wrong way to do it. You should pass `-pthread` to both compile and link steps which will link the pthread library **and also set any preprocessor defines and other required compile options**.

Comment: @ZanLynx Same Issue even if i change it to `-pthread` in `Makefile`

Comment: @ZanLynx: `-lpthread` is perfectly valid and is the standard POSIX-documented way to ensure the pthread inerfaces are available. `-pthread` is legacy GCC stuff from back when you used to need `-D_REENTRANT` and other wackiness to get working threads.

Comment: Did you add more code after this line? https://github.com/sachinites/tcpip_stack/blob/Hellos/WheelTimer/WheelTimer.h#L50 Because some array of size 0 is an **non-standard hack** in C and can only be used at the end of a structure as a way to use `malloc` and friends to allocate more space at the end of the structure, then access it by that zero-length array name. But you've put more struct elements after it, which will get overwritten.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html

Comment: @ZanLynx Thanks a lot !!  Pushed the zero length array member as the last member of the structure, and issue is gone. I was aware of such C problems, but did not stuck to me this time. Thanks a lot once again. No core is seen !!

Comment: @R.. And on systems that use a thread runtime library. And any other settings that may happen in the future. Just use `-pthread` it isn't going to hurt you.

Comment: @R.. And check gcc -dumpstats looks like it also adjusts things for correct profiling without which it would be *wrong*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with my Data structure, in which zero length array was the non-last member of the C structure which corrupt memory when read/written into such arrays. Stretchable arrays should be last member of the structures.

```
typedef struct _wheel_timer_t {
    int current_clock_tic;
    int clock_tic_interval;
    int wheel_size;
    int current_cycle_no;
    pthread_t wheel_thread;
    slotlist_t slotlist[0];            << problem, make it last member
    slotlist_t reschd_list;
    unsigned int no_of_wt_elem;
    pthread_mutex_t global_lock;
} wheel_timer_t;
```

Comment: `[0]` is a GNU extension and is not valid C. It should be `[]`, and then the compiler would give you an error if it's not at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Almost surely your `wheel_timer_t` structure has a `global_lock` member of type `pthread_mutex_t *` rather than `pthread_mutex_t`, meaning that you're passing a pointer of the wrong type, that points to only 8 bytes of storage (assuming a 64-bit implementation), to `pthread_mutex_lock`. This would be detected if you used compiler warnings; `pthread_mutex_t **` cannot convert implicitly to `pthread_mutex_t *` and the compiler should issue a diagnostic for this.

Note that this probably means you have significant other errors and that your mutex is not properly initialized.

Comment: No, `wheel_timer_t` has `pthread_mutex_t global_lock` as a member, it is not a pointer member.

typedef struct _wheel_timer_t {

    pthread_mutex_t global_lock;

} wheel_timer_t;

This was the first thing i cross-checked.

Answer (score 0):

This was the top question when I was googling around for `../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c: No such file or directory.`, so I figured I'd post the fix for me.

In my case, I was trying to make an interactive marker server with ROS, but I kept getting this segfault. When I got into it with gdb I saw the error I mentioned above, and could NOT figure out what was going on with a `mutex` because there simply weren't any in my code.

It turns out that my `interactive_markers::InteractiveMarkerServer server` is not actually an InteractiveMarkerSever, but instead it's a **smart pointer that was not initialized!**

I have no idea why I didn't just get a null reference exception or something else. No idea why it went to a mutex file missing, but when I initialized the pointer the error went away. My class definition has:

```
std::shared_ptr<interactive_markers::InteractiveMarkerServer> server;
```

And when I added:

```
server = std::make_shared<interactive_markers::InteractiveMarkerServer>("ns", "id", false);
```

to the class constructor I stopped getting the error.